# Importing custom class inside a controller

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, namespaces, cakephp-3.0

I created a class at Controller folder of Cake project like this:

```
<?php
class Hi
{
    function __construct(){ }

    public function hi()
    {
        echo "hi!";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Then in a controller, I tried to include it:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
include_once "Hi.php";

class MyController extends AppController
{
    public function sayHi()
    {
        $a = new Hi();
        $a.hi();
    }
}
```

Here is the error I'm having:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class Hi, because the name is already in use in path\api\src\Controller\Hi.php on line 2

What's going on?

`MyController.php` and `Hi.php` are in the same folder. I'm using PHP 7.

Comment: Dunno, but what is `$a.hi();`???

Comment: It's just to test...

Comment: Now I understood hahahah... It's `$a->hi();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including a file won't make the classes in that file part of the current namespace, as namespaces are a per-file functionality.

**[http://php.net/...namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope)**

Your `Hi` class will be declared in the global namespace, and your `new Hi()` will cause PHP to look for it in the current namespace, ie it will look for `App\Controller\Hi`, which doesn't exist, hence the composer autoloader kicks in, and will map this via a PSR-4 namespace prefix match to `src/Controller/Hi.php`, which will include the file again, and that's when it happens.

**http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/**

Long story short, while using `new \Hi()` would fix this, you better not include class files manually, or declare them in paths where they do not belong. Instead declare your files and classes in a proper autoloading compatible fashion, that is for example with a proper namespace in a path that matches that namespace, like

```
namespace App\Utils;

class Hi {
    // ...
}
```

in

```
src/Utils/Hi.php
```